# Generic constraint for Action doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, .net, generics, covariance, contravariance

I am having some trouble understanding why the following snippet does not give me an error

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(T arg) where T : MyInterface
{
  MyInterface e = arg;
}
```

But this one, which I would expect to work due to the generic type constraint

```
private readonly IList<Action<MyInterface>> myActionList = new List<Action<MyInterface>>();

public IDisposable Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback) where T: MyInterface
{
  myActionList.Add(callback); // doesn't compile
  return null
}
```

Gives this error

```
cannot convert from 'System.Action<T>' to 'System.Action<MyInterface>'
```

I am using VS2012 sp1 and .NET 4.5.

Can anyone explain why the constraint does not allow this to compile?

Comment: Why is your list readonly, and why `new IList`? Is that the actual declaration?

Comment: Classes and delegates are not the same thing. `System.Action<MyInterface>` represents a function with a single parameter of type `MyInterface` whilst `System.Action<T>` represents a method with a parameter of type `T : MyInterface`. The function signatures are not compatible, it is not relevent that `T` is a derivative of `MyInterface`, the signature would only be compatible if `T` was exactly `MyInterface`.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco apologies, it's reconstructed and simplified from some other code. Copy/Paste error

Comment: @jamesj: no problem, thanks for fixing it, and good question btw :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes and delegates are not the same thing. `System.Action<MyInterface>` represents a function with a single parameter of type `MyInterface` whilst `System.Action<T>` represents a method with a parameter of type `T : MyInterface`. The function signatures are not compatible, it is not relevent that `T` is a derivative of `MyInterface`, the signature would only be compatible if `T` was exactly `MyInterface`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a contravariance issue - an `Action<MyInterface>` should be able to take any `MyInterface` instance as an argument, however you are trying to store an `Action<T>` where `T` is some subtype of `MyInterface`, which is not safe.

For example if you had:

```
public class SomeImpl : MyInterface { }
public class SomeOtherImpl : MyInterface { }
List<Action<MyInterface>> list;

list.Add(new Action<SomeImpl>(i => { }));
ActionMyInterface act = list[0];
act(new SomeOtherImpl());
```

You can only assign an `Action<T>` to some `Action<U>` if the type `T` is 'smaller' than the type `U`. For example

```
Action<string> act = new Action<object>(o => { });
```

is safe since a string argument is always valid where an object argument is.

Answer (score 2):

The `where T: MyInterface` constraint means "**any** instance of **any** class or struct which implements MyInterface".

So what you are trying to do can be simplified as this:

```
Action<IList> listAction = null;
Action<IEnumerable> enumAction = listAction;
```

Which is not supposed to work, while still `IList : IEnumerable`. More details can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

So if you **really** need to use generic and not just interface - you can do it like this, though it adds complexity and minor performance issues:

```
public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : MyInterface
{
    myActionList.Add(t => callback((T)t)); // this compiles and work
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I find it helpful in these situations to consider what goes wrong if you allow the behaviour. So let's consider that.

```
interface IAnimal { void Eat(); }
class Tiger : IAnimal 
{ 
  public void Eat() { ... }
  public void Pounce() { ... } 
}
class Giraffe : IAnimal 
...
public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback) where T: IAnimal
{
   Action<IAnimal> myAction = callback; // doesn't compile but pretend it does.
   myAction(new Giraffe()); // Obviously legal; Giraffe implements IAnimal
}
...
Subscribe<Tiger>((Tiger t)=>{ t.Pounce(); });
```

So what happens?  We create a delegate that takes a tiger and pounces, pass that to `Subscribe<Tiger>`, convert that to `Action<IAnimal>`, and pass a giraffe, which then pounces.

Obviously that has to be illegal. The only place where it is sensible to make it illegal is the conversion from `Action<Tiger>` to `Action<IAnimal>`. So that's where it is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

Classes and delegates behave a little different. Let's see a simple example:

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(T arg) where T : MyInterface
{
  MyInterface e = arg;
}
```

In this method you could assume that T would be at least `MyInterface`, so you could do something like this `MyInterface e = arg;` because args always could be cast to `MyInterface`.

Now let's see how delegates behave:

```
public class BaseClass { };
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass { };
private readonly IList<Action<BaseClass >> myActionList = new List<Action<BaseClass>>();

public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback) where T: BaseClass
{
  myActionList.Add(callback); // so you could add more 'derived' callback here Action<DerivedClass>
  return null;
}
```

Now we'r adding DerivedClass callback to myActionList and then somewhere you invoke delegates:

```
foreach( var action in myActionList ) {
   action(new BaseClass);
}
```

But you can't do that, because if you have DerivedClass callback you have to pass it DerivedClass as parameter.

This question refers to [Covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). You could read about variance from [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) article, also Eric Lippert has very intersting articles about variance, [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx) is the first article, you can find the rest in his blog.

P.S. Edited accorind to Lee comment.

Comment: Classes cannot be covariant - only delegates and interfaces can have variance annotations. It's also misleading to say delegates 'have' contravariance - the `Func` delegate types are contravariant in their arguments and covariant in their return types. Contravariance is not restricted to delegate types, see the `IObserver<T>` interface for example, which is contravariant in `T`.

Answer (score 0):

If `T` is limited to a certain interface anyway, you could just use that interface in its stead:

```
public void SomeMethod(MyInterface arg)
{
  MyInterface e = arg;
}

private readonly IList<Action<MyInterface>> myActionList = new IList<Action<MyInterface>>();

public IDisposable Subscribe(Action<MyInterface> callback)
{
  myActionList.Add(callback); // does compile
  return null
}
```

Will work and compile and is practically the same as what you have now.

Generics are useful if you want to do the same operation REGARDLESS of the type, if you then limit the type to some interface you have defeated the purpose of generics and should probably just use that interface instead.

Comment: I guess he wants to be able to pass subtypes of that specific interface.. eg. MyOtherInterface : MyInterface

Comment: @Roger that might be true, I did not get that from the OP but I do admit it's an approach I did not consider either.