# How to store Action delegates with constrained generic type in a type safe collection in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Let's say I want to store delegates in a collection like this:

```
public void AddDelegate<T>(Action<T> action) where T : ISomething
{
   _delegates.Add(action);
}
```

What should the type of `_delegates` be?

Trying with `IList<Action<ISomething>> _delegates;`
results in error message **`Argument type 'System.Action<T>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Action<ISomething>'`** for the `Add` call above. But why doesn't it work? The compiler should 'know' that T must be an `ISomething`.
What are my options if I don't want to loose type safety by using e.g. a `IList<object>` or parameterize the whole class on the generic type `T`?

Comment: could you wrap the collection in `public class DelegateCollection<T> where T : ISomething`?

Comment: @DavidArno has a much better answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_delegates` has to be of type `IList<Action<T>>`.

Therefore you have to add the `<T> where T : ISomething` to the class.

Alternatively, do away with the generics and support `Action<ISomething>` directly.

So your two options are:

```
public class Delegates<T> where T : ISomething
{
    private List<Action<T>> _delegates;

    public void AddDelegate(Action<T> action)
    {
        _delegates.Add(action);
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class Delegates
{
    private List<Action<ISomething>> _delegates;

    public void AddDelegate(Action<ISomething> action)
    {
        _delegates.Add(action);
    }
}
```

**Edit**
[As Sehnsucht points out, there's a third option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30530260/7122): wrap the `Action<T>` delegate inside an `Action<ISomething>` delegate and then the OP can achieve what he originally wanted.

The reason for this is that whilst `T` is a "subtype" (implementer) of `ISomething`, `Action<T>` is not a subtype of `Action<ISomething>`, in fact [as dcastro explains in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30530170/7122), the opposite is actually true (despite that seeming counter-intuitive). Even with casting, you cannot add an instance of `Action<T>` to a list of `Action<ISomething>`.

Answer (score 3):

you should see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610892/generic-constraint-for-action-doesnt-work-as-expected) for more insight to the problem

I can propose that "kind of hack" to circumvent the problem but I can't say if it's a good thing or really just a hack.

```
    void Add<T> (Action<T> action) where T : ISomething
    {
        Action<ISomething> typedAction = something => action ((T) something);
        _delegates.Add (typedAction);
    }
```

Comment: I'd not call that a hack. It's a good thing IMO. I'll update my answer to reference this as a third option.

Comment: That's actually a really clever workaround, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> But why doesn't it work? The compiler should 'know' that T must be an ISomething.

`Action<in T>` is contravariant in `T`, which means `Action<Derived>` is not a subtype of `Action<Base>`, even though `Derived` is a subtype of `Base`.

In fact, contravariance means the opposite: `Action<Derived>` is a *supertype* of `Action<Base>`. That is, an `Action<object>` can be assigned to an `Action<string>`.

In your case, `Action<T> where T : ISomething` cannot be assigned to an `Action<ISomething>`, but the opposite would be possible.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It kind of does. OP posed a two part question: Why doesn't this work, and what are my options? I've answer the first part, David Arno answered the second.

Answer (score 1):

Your example won't work because while the compiler knows `T` is `ISomething` it doesn't know *which* subtype of `ISomething` will be provided. It can only be done safely if the provided type will always be a subtype of the parameter type

This is would be unsafe for example:

```
class FirstSomething : ISomething { }
class SecondSomething : ISomething { }
Action<FirstSomething> act = f => { }
Action<ISomething> sa = act; //not allowed
sa(new SecondSomething());   //unsafe!
```

`Action<T>` is contravariant in `T` which means it can only be assigned to an `Action<U>` if `U` is a subtype of `T`, which it is not in your case since `ISomething` is a supertype of `T`.