# How to filter a collection of delegates based on their parameter's generic type in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, delegates

I have a collection of delegates:

```
IList<Action<ISomeInterface>> _delegates = new List<Action<ISomeInterface>>();
```

And a method* to add delegates to it**:

```
public void AddDelegate<T>(Action<T> del) where T : ISomeInterface
{
    _delegates.Add(si => del((T)si));   
}
```

Now I want to filter the delegates collection based on the concrete type the delegate is constructed with:

```
var aDelegates = _delegates.Where(d => d is Action<SomeInterfaceImplA>);
foreach(var del in aDelegates)
{
   ....
}
```

Which will return all delegates, not only `Action<SomeInterfaceImplA>` delegates. So my question is, what predicate should be used in the `Where` clause to get the correct subset from the filtering? Full code example is available [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7dBIob).
<sub>* A fluent API (generic) method is using it hence the use of a generic type here</sub>  
<sub>** Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30530260/360674)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not be the prettiest thing ever, but it works

```
    var aDelegates = someClass.Delegates.Where(d => 
        d.Method.DeclaringType.GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SomeInterfaceImplA)));
```

Comment: Oh, and of course, if you want a different equality predicate than `IsAssignableFrom`, you can also switch it up to check for classes specifically with `IsSubclassOf` or straight up equality with `==`. Also, you can add some null checking logic in there to make it safer. If you are using C# 6, you can even put some null propagation operators to avoid potential null references without extracting the lambda logic to a separate method, 

ex: `someClass.Delegates.Where(d =>         d?.Method?.DeclaringType?.GenericTypeArguments?.FirstOrDefault()?.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SomeInterfaceImplA)) ?? false)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that the construction you have currently makes any sense. You may want to change what you are doing if you want to filter your delegates by concrete expected implementation argument type, by changing this:

```
IList<Action<ISomeInterface>> _delegates = new List<Action<ISomeInterface>>();
```

to this:

```
IDictionary<Type, List<Action<ISomeInterface>>> _delegates = 
    new Dictionary<Type, List<Action<ISomeInterface>>>();
```

And the `AddDelegate` method to

```
public void AddDelegate<T>(Action<T> del) where T : ISomeInterface
{
    var list = default(List<Action<ISomeInterface>>);
    if (!_delegates.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list))
        _delegates[typeof(T)] = list = new List<Action<ISomeInterface>>();
     list.Add(si => del((T)si));   
}
```

And use the dictionary to filter by argument type.

The reason why your current code will not work, is that all of the registered actions are actually of type `Action<ISomeInterface>`, that their method body (`si => del((T)si`) performs a **dangerous** cast of its argument to a type `T` does not change that.